# I am trying to implement the Paging3 in my Project but stucked in pager in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, paging

Here I am implementing paging3 in my project (java) android

it is my paging source

```
ublic class CycleEventPPagingSource extends PagingSource<Integer, CycleEventData> {


ApiInterface apiInterface;
String authorization, access_token, rider_id, latitude, longitude, location;

public CycleEventPPagingSource(ApiInterface apiInterface, String authorization, String access_token, String rider_id, String latitude, String longitude, String location) {
    this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
    this.authorization = authorization;
    this.access_token = access_token;
    this.rider_id = rider_id;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.location = location;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object load(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> loadParams,
                   @NonNull Continuation<? super LoadResult<Integer, CycleEventData>> continuation) {

    try {

        int pageNumber = loadParams.getKey() != null ? loadParams.getKey() : 1;
        String npageNumber = String.valueOf(pageNumber);


        Response<CycleEventResponse> response = apiInterface.get_Cycle_Event_List(authorization, access_token, rider_id, latitude, longitude, location, npageNumber);

        Integer prevKey = (pageNumber == 1) ? null : pageNumber - 1;
        Integer nextKey = pageNumber + 1;

        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            ArrayList<CycleEventData> data = (ArrayList<CycleEventData>) response.body().getData();

            return new LoadResult.Page(
                    data,
                    prevKey,
                    nextKey
            );
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Integer getRefreshKey(@NonNull PagingState<Integer, CycleEventData> pagingState) {
    return 1;
}
```

}

This is my api interface

```
@GET(AppConstant.API_CYCLE_EVENT_LIST)
Response<CycleEventResponse> get_Cycle_Event_List(@Query("Authorization") String Authorization,
                                                  @Header("access_token") String access_token,
                                                  @Query("rider_id") String rider_id,
                                                  @Query("latitude") String latitude,
                                                  @Query("longitude") String longitude,
                                                  @Query("location") String location,
                                                  @Query("page_no") String page_no);
```

These are the model classs

public class CycleEventResponse {

```
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private ArrayList<String> message;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<CycleEventData> data;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;


@SerializedName("base_url")
@Expose
private String base_url;


@SerializedName("gallery_data")
@Expose
public ArrayList<String> gallery_data;

public ArrayList<String> getGallery_data() {
    return gallery_data;
}

public void setGallery_data(ArrayList<String> gallery_data) {
    this.gallery_data = gallery_data;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(ArrayList<String> message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<CycleEventData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<CycleEventData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getBase_url() {
    return base_url;
}

public void setBase_url(String base_url) {
    this.base_url = base_url;
}
```

}

public class CycleEventData {

```
@SerializedName("event_id")
@Expose
public String event_id;

@SerializedName("event_name")
@Expose
public String event_name;

@SerializedName("event_date")
@Expose
public String event_date;

@SerializedName("eligibility")
@Expose
public String eligibility;

@SerializedName("event_img")
@Expose
public String event_img;

@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
public String latitude;

@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
public String longitude;

@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
public String description;

@SerializedName("venue")
@Expose
public String venue;

@SerializedName("people_limit")
@Expose
public String people_limit;

@SerializedName("fee_type")
@Expose
public String fee_type;

@SerializedName("event_timing")
@Expose
public String event_timing;


@SerializedName("location")
@Expose
public String location;

@SerializedName("fee_amount")
@Expose
public int fee_amount;

@SerializedName("distance")
@Expose
public double distance;

@SerializedName("event_url")
@Expose
public String event_url;


public String getEvent_url() {
    return event_url;
}

public void setEvent_url(String event_url) {
    this.event_url = event_url;
}

public String getEvent_timing() {
    return event_timing;
}

public void setEvent_timing(String event_timing) {
    this.event_timing = event_timing;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getEvent_id() {
    return event_id;
}

public void setEvent_id(String event_id) {
    this.event_id = event_id;
}

public String getEvent_name() {
    return event_name;
}

public void setEvent_name(String event_name) {
    this.event_name = event_name;
}

public String getEvent_date() {
    return event_date;
}

public void setEvent_date(String event_date) {
    this.event_date = event_date;
}

public String getEligibility() {
    return eligibility;
}

public void setEligibility(String eligibility) {
    this.eligibility = eligibility;
}

public String getEvent_img() {
    return event_img;
}

public void setEvent_img(String event_img) {
    this.event_img = event_img;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getVenue() {
    return venue;
}

public void setVenue(String venue) {
    this.venue = venue;
}

public String getPeople_limit() {
    return people_limit;
}

public void setPeople_limit(String people_limit) {
    this.people_limit = people_limit;
}

public String getFee_type() {
    return fee_type;
}

public void setFee_type(String fee_type) {
    this.fee_type = fee_type;
}

public int getFee_amount() {
    return fee_amount;
}

public void setFee_amount(int fee_amount) {
    this.fee_amount = fee_amount;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
```

}

i am not able to create the pager i am sharing my all the dependencies

These are the dependencies are used

```
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation project(path: ':library')
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


// Glide Dependency
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1"

//for rx java and live data
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

//for okHttp
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.2'

//for retrofit mvvm
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0"

// Google place
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

//for fcm
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

//for QR code and barcode scanner
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'

//for google map
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayVersion"

//for map duration
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.5'

implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'


//for custom calendar
implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.0'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.7.2'

implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.4'

implementation 'com.github.Drjacky:ImagePicker:2.3.22'

implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0'

implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.cachapa:ExpandableLayout:2.9.2'


implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.4'

//discrete scroll view
implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1'

implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.2.1"

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.ismaeldivita:chip-navigation-bar:1.4.0'

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```

//  implementation 'com.github.Inconnu08:android-ratingreviews:1.2.0'

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.jhonnyx2012:horizontal-picker:1.0.6'
```

//   implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:3.0.3'

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

// Image Opener
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view-androidx:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

//Picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

// Paging dependency Injection
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0"
```

//   implementation("androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2:3.1.1")
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1"